# WSO2 WebDav integration

Tags: wso2, webdav, mediator

how to upload file in WebDAV using WSO2 mediator ?

in developer doc it says its support WebDAV integration but I couldn't get any example to upload a file. 
Reading a file from WebDAV https is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 implementation on Apache Commons VFS library does not support the WebDAV support over VFS.

You can implement a custom mediator to achive WebDAV operations. using sample libraries like JackRabbit WebDAV library